# vlc not shows its window, looks like it hanging

Tags: vlc

Several days ago I upgrade ubuntu to 13.04. And after that I cannot run vlc. Output:

```
$ vlc -vvv
VLC media player 2.0.6 Twoflower (revision 2.0.6-0-gbe9623c)
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.0.6 Twoflower
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2013 VLC authors and VideoLAN
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: revision 2.0.6-0-gbe9623c
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: configured with ./configure  '--enable-static' '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' '--config-cache' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-silent-rules' '--disable-update-check' '--enable-fast-install' '--prefix=/usr' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/vlc-nox' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--with-binary-version=1' '--enable-a52' '--enable-aa' '--enable-bluray' '--enable-bonjour' '--enable-caca' '--enable-dbus' '--enable-dca' '--enable-dirac' '--enable-directfb' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--enable-dvdnav' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-fluidsynth' '--enable-freetype' '--enable-fribidi' '--enable-gnutls' '--enable-jack' '--enable-kate' '--enable-libass' '--enable-libmpeg2' '--enable-libproxy' '--enable-libxml2' '--enable-lirc' '--enable-live555' '--enable-mad' '--enable-mkv' '--enable-mod' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-mtp' '--enable-mux_ogg' '--enable-ncurses' '--enable-notify' '--enable-ogg' '--enable-opus' '--enable-oss' '--enable-pulse' '--enable-qt4' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-samplerate' '--enable-schroedinger' '--enable-sdl' '--enable-sftp' '--enable-shout' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-smb' '--enable-speex' '--enable-svg' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-theora' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-upnp' '--enable-vcd' '--enable-vcdx' '--enable-vorbis' '--enable-x264' '--enable-zvbi' '--with-kde-solid=/usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/' '--disable-dxva2' '--disable-gnomevfs' '--disable-goom' '--disable-portaudio' '--disable-projectm' '--disable-sqlite' '--disable-telx' '--enable-alsa' '--enable-atmo' '--enable-dc1394' '--enable-dv' '--enable-fbosd' '--enable-libva' '--enable-linsys' '--enable-omxil' '--enable-pvr' '--enable-udev' '--enable-v4l2' '--enable-crystalhd' '--enable-mmx' '--enable-sse' '--disable-neon' '--disable-altivec' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu'
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins'
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: saving plugins cache /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 422 modules
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: opening config file (/home/al/.config/vlc/vlcrc)
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "C"
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 FPU 
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: looking for memcpy module: 4 candidates
[0x9f4108] main libvlc debug: using memcpy module "memcpymmxext"
[0xd46608] main input debug: Creating an input for 'Media Library'
[0xd46608] main input debug: Input is a meta file: disabling unneeded options
[0xd46608] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
[0xd46608] main input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/al/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' gives access `file' demux `xspf-open' path `/home/al/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0xd46608] main input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/al/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/al/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0xa08038] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module: 3 candidates
[0xa08038] main demux debug: no access_demux module matching "file" could be loaded
[0xa08038] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.655 ms - Total 1.655 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.655 ms)
[0xd46608] main input debug: creating access 'file' location='/home/al/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf', path='/home/al/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0xc3ad58] main access debug: looking for access module: 2 candidates
[0xc3ad58] filesystem access debug: opening file `/home/al/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0xc3ad58] main access debug: using access module "filesystem"
[0xc3ad58] main access debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.945 ms - Total 0.945 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.945 ms)
[0xc3b588] main stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[0xc3b588] main stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[0xc3b588] main stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
[0xc3b588] main stream debug: pre-buffering done 296 bytes in 0s - 1513 KiB/s
[0xa09f28] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 7 candidates
[0xa09f28] main stream debug: no stream_filter module matching "any" could be loaded
[0xa09f28] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.308 ms - Total 1.308 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.308 ms)
[0xa09f28] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 1 candidate
[0xa09f28] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "stream_filter_record"
[0xa09f28] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.535 ms - Total 0.535 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.535 ms)
[0xd46608] main input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/al/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/al/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0xa229b8] main demux debug: looking for demux module: 1 candidate
[0xa229b8] playlist demux debug: using XSPF playlist reader
[0xa229b8] main demux debug: using demux module "playlist"
[0xa229b8] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.788 ms - Total 0.788 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.788 ms)
[0xa232e8] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module: 2 candidates
[0xa232e8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/al/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0xa232e8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0xa232e8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
[0xa232e8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0xa232e8] main demux meta debug: no meta reader module matching "any" could be loaded
[0xa232e8] main demux meta debug: TIMER module_need() : 3.368 ms - Total 3.368 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 3.368 ms)
[0xd46608] main input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/al/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' successfully opened
[0xacb4e8] main xml reader debug: looking for xml reader module: 1 candidate
[0xacb4e8] main xml reader debug: using xml reader module "xml"
[0xacb4e8] main xml reader debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.198 ms - Total 1.198 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.198 ms)
[0xa229b8] playlist demux debug: parsed 0 tracks successfully
[0xd46608] main input debug: EOF reached
[0xa229b8] main demux debug: removing module "playlist"
[0xa09f28] main stream debug: removing module "stream_filter_record"
[0xc3ad58] main access debug: removing module "filesystem"
[0xd46608] main input debug: TIMER input launching for 'Media Library' : 12.257 ms - Total 12.257 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 12.257 ms)
[0xac8ec8] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
[0xac8ec8] main interface debug: using interface module "hotkeys"
[0xac8ec8] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.638 ms - Total 0.638 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.638 ms)
[0xd52e18] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
[0xc38448] main playlist debug: playlist threads correctly activated
[0xd52e18] main interface debug: using interface module "inhibit"
[0xd52e18] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 3.581 ms - Total 3.581 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 3.581 ms)
[0xc3b588] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
[0xc38448] main playlist debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
[0xc3b588] main interface debug: using interface module "globalhotkeys"
[0xc3b588] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.561 ms - Total 1.561 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.561 ms)
[0x9f4108] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0xc339f8] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 6 candidates
[0xc38448] main playlist debug: rebuild done - 0 items, index -1
```

Vlc settings from .cache and .local in user folder already deleted.

But sometimes (rarely) it run normally and vlc window appear and it's work! Doesn't matter where vlc - from package or compiled from source.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete it from Synptic as full removal then try to install it maybe it'll fix the problem

Comment: I tried this three times (remove and purge). No effect.